# Google Maps url to login as a specific user

Tags: google-maps

For Google Mail I can choose the local user in the url via:

```
mail.google.com/mail/u/<place local user number here>
```

e.g.

```
mail.google.com/mail/u/1
```

Is there anything like that for Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a query-parameter `authuser` with the desired user-number

```
https://www.google.com/maps/?authuser=<place local user number here>
```